# WPF user Align items

Tags: wpf, alignment

My app needs to have items in be aligned by the user; left, right and center. I am having an issue formating the app to handle this, meaning that application can either align left or right or center but not all three.  How can I get the items for example 5 buttons to be aligned left, right and center changed via a button press (I should know how to do this once I am able to actual format in XMLA)?

My first thought would be do this with a dock panel;

```
<DockPanel MinWidth="500" Background="LightGray" Margin="20" LastChildFill="False">
   <Button Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Left" >one</Button>
   <Button Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Left">two</Button>
   <Button Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Left">three</Button>
   <Button Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Left">four</Button>
   <Button Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Left">five</Button>
</DockPanel>
```

This works great for Left and right alignment.  The problem is that there is no DockPanel.Dock="Center"

Next tried a Grid;

```
<Grid Background="LightGray" MinWidth="500">
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,10,10">one</Button>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,10,10">two</Button>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,10,10">three</Button>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,10,10">four</Button>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,10,10">five</Button>
</Grid>
```

Problem is that this happens;

[image]

edit:  Apparently I didn't make the my question clear enough.

edit2:  @Henka Programmer suggestion below did not work.  First I believe he meant HorizontalAlignment not VerticalAlignment.  With this code;

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="LightGray" MinWidth="500">
<Button Content="btn 01" />
<Button Content="btn 02" />
<Button Content="btn 03" />
<Button Content="btn 0" />
</StackPanel>
```

Gives this result;

[image]

Changing `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` to `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` makes no difference

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @HighCore see edit above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The horizontal alignment property on the StackPanel is going to align the StackPanel relative to its parent element.  This works just fine:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="1000">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Button Content="Button 1" />
        <Button Content="Button 2" />
        <Button Content="Button 3" />
        <Button Content="Button 4" />
        <Button Content="Button 5" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you mean this:

```
// ...
<Grid>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
<Button Content="btn 01" />
<Button Content="btn 02" />
<Button Content="btn 03" />
<Button Content="btn 0" />
</StackPanel>

</Grid>
// ...
```

and you can change the alignment of StackPanel with:

- VeriticalAlignment="Center"
- VeriticalAlignment="Right"
- VeriticalAlignment="Left"

and the StackPanel Orientation :

- Vertical
- Horizontal

Comment: I think you meant HorizontalAlignment not VerticalAlignment, seeing that there is no Right or Left in VerticalAlignment.  Also this did not work, see edit for details